# How to select which layer to show on a map?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, layer

If I had an array of layers added to my map, i.e.:

```
   for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
        lyr = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
        layer.push(lyr);
        lyr.addTo(mymap);
        }
```

how can I select programmatically which layer[i] to show? I can't find any available function in Leaflet docs...

Comment: Do you mean let the user select which layer (s)he wants to show? In that case, what about the [Layers Control](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)?

Comment: No, sorry. How can I select it programmatically.
I am going to edit the question.

Comment: Then it sounds like just a matter of programming, using [`addTo`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layer-addto) and [`remove`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layer-remove). BTW check the syntax for [`array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: The layers are all already added to the map. It is a matter to select the one when needed.

Comment: Let's imagine I need to loop through the layers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your layer to a `featureGroup` when you create it. A great idea is to add a name to your layer so it will be simpler to get it after :

```
var group = new L.featureGroup();
for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
     lyr = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
     layer.push(lyr);
     layer.name = 'My_layer ...';
     lyr.addTo(group);
}
mymap.addLayer(group);
```

In this example, for me, each iteration provide a layer. You add it to your group and wait the end of the loop to add it to the map.

To show or hide you will need this function :

```
function showHideTile(tileToShowOrHide)
{
    group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.eachLayer(function(yourLayer) {
            //Do your test here
            if (yourLayer == tileToShowOrHide) {
                //To add the layer to your map
                map.addLayer(yourLayer);
            } else {
                //To remove the layer
                map.removeLayer(yourLayer);                
            }
            //You can also send an array to this function
            //With the layer name and what you want to do
            //Ex : tile1 hide
        })
    })
}
```

Not the best way but it will give you something to start with.

Comment: why `group._layers[yourLayer._leaflet_id]` instead of just `yourLayer`?

Comment: You seem to assume that `group` contains Layer Groups, but OP uses Tile Layers.

Comment: I took it from my code but I've edited. Yeah but you can add your Tile Layers to a featuregroup

Comment: Once added all the layers to featureGroup, can't I use the bringToFront method to show the one I need?

Comment: Well, never used it but I don't get the idea. For me it's better to add and remove layer from the map

Comment: Baptiste, but you are removing the layer in the same loop in which you add it... I was thinking to loop through layers, so maybe adding/removing could be more intensive than just "bringToFront"?

Comment: No no it's an example. You need to add a condition to know if you have to remove/add the layer. For example, you call your function where you have the `group.eachLayer`. Then before adding or removing you add a if (I'm updating the answer)

Comment: I tested it with layer[i].bringToFront() and it is working. Anyway I am going to accept your answer as it pointed me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @FabioMarzocca having all your layers on map impacts performance, so if most of them are hidden, better simply remove them from map. It will be much less intensive for the browser to add and remove than having all of them on map. Now if you want to pre-fetch the tiles, that is a slightly different story.

Comment: I am not adding the layers with mymap.addTo(). Just using your first function to load them into the group, and then just fire bringToFront.

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Glad I could help you !

Answer (score 0):

I did this way.

1- load the layers into the group:

```
var group = new L.featureGroup();
for (i = 0; i < myoptionsArray.length; i++) {
     lyr = L.tileLayer.wms(url, {optionsArray[i]});
     layer.push(lyr);
     lyr.addTo(group);
}
mymap.addLayer(group);
```

2 - Then I added a function to show the layer I need:

```
function showLayer(i) {
 layer[i].bringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Just one problem. During the loop to load the layers into the group, they are all showing in sequence on the map. Couldn't this be done without displaying them?

Comment: If you're doing directly `mymap.addLayer(group);` it's logic. Just remove it